# Eclipse to get program execution time

Tags: performance, eclipse

OS:WinXP

Under UNIX-like environment, we can get execution time by `$time ./my_program`. I wonder we can get execution time info in Eclipse? Is it possible to do this without a profiler? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the TPTP Eclipse plugin has this feature: http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/

You could get an approximation of it by the difference of timestamps:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();;
    new MyApplication();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();;

    System.out.println((end - start) + " ms");
  }
```

This will print the runtime in ms.

Comment: TPTP is discontinued. Is there anything current?

Answer (score -1):

You can configure how to run your program. Go to menu Run | Run ... to open up the Run Dialog Window. Add the `time` command to show the runtime in the console.