# How to find execution time of a program in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Regardless of language used (C++, Java etc.), is there a way in Eclipse to show the execution time of a program from start to finish?

An earlier question - [Eclipse to get program execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126631/eclipse-to-get-program-execution-time) did not satisfactorily answer this.

Comment: Why did the earlier question not answer your issue? More details please.

Comment: The first answer mentions a discontinued library. The second answer is incomplete, but seems to suggest there is a way of doing it nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//code
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiling tools in Eclipse as shown in the below link
[Eclipse - Profiling Monitor][1]

```
  [1]: http://eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html
```

or you can also use CLOCKS_PER_SEC declared in 'time.h' like

```
clock_t begin, end;
double time;
begin = clock();
end = clock();
time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```